# Display mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you display the position of mouse in a div ? The values displayed in the div should change once we move the mouse to a new position.

HTML

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

CSS

```
#info{
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
right:20px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
}
```

I want the position of the mouse to be displayed inside the black div "info".The value inside must be refreshed during every movement & should display the location of the mouse whenever we move it.

Comment: SO is not a script requesting website. The idea is that you show us what you have tried and what exact problem you are encountering. We will then help you. Luckily for you Richard is that kind to just give what you've asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jelmer.I made some research before asking this question here to do the same.But was not satisfied with most of the results  as i am a beginner.I was pretty sure that the script for this will not be that long & will be much easier for the professionals here.Hoping a helping answer i just asked the thing.Sorry guys if that was a wrong turn. Accepting the down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jQuery solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on("mousemove", function(event) {
        var position = "X Coordinate: " + event.pageX + " Y Coordinate: " + event.pageY
        $("div").filter("#info").text(position);       
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7zkvnqr/1/

First, you listen for the `mousemove` event and it's important to pass in `event` as a parameter.

You now want to declare a variable, using the `pageX` and `pageY` properties. These return the x and y coordinates of your mouse position respectively.

Then use the `text()` function and pass in the new position variable you just defined.

Here is a JavaScript solution

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    var div = document.querySelector("#info");
    var position = "X Coordinate: " + event.clientX + " Y Coordinate: " + event.clientY;
    div.innerHTML(position);
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! simple & was really looking for this.

Comment: Will do , don't forget that the question too have an arrow to upvote lol ! @Richard Hamilton